# Hooking sycalls from userspace on Linux

Tags: linux, hook, system-calls, code-injection, patch

Is there any way to catch all syscalls on Linux? The only solution I know of is using LD_PRELOAD à la [fakeroot](http://packages.qa.debian.org/f/fakeroot.html), but that only works for dynamically linked applications. Furthermore, this approach requires enumerating all syscalls which is something I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`ptrace(2)`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100).

Answer (score 0):

You can trace a program. Think about how `strace` works. Hint: it doesn't use `LD_PRELOAD` tricks.